# Sending mail with Powershell Windows 7

Tags: email, powershell

I cant get this to work on a windows 7 client with powershell 2

```
 $smtpServer = "smtp.example.com"
 $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
 $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
 $msg.From = "fromID@example.com"
 $msg.ReplyTo = "replyto@example.com"
 $msg.To.Add("toID@example.com")
 $msg.subject = "My Subject"
 $msg.body = "This is the email Body."
 $smtp.Send($msg)
```

I am getting an exception that says "Exception calling "Send with "1" arguments" Failure Sending mail"
Anyone have any idea?
I have tried Send-MailMessage but it also fails, if I run the command on a server based windows it executes fine. 
I use the same account for the procedures.

Comment: Please show the exact error you're getting. Can you connect to `$smtpServer` at all? Check with `telnet smtp.xxxx.com 25`.

Comment: Show the exact error you get, especially when you use `Send-MailMessage` (which is preferable over `Net.Mail`).

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to many reasons, but one issue that I had seen this exact same error was because an anti-virus program was blocking Powershell from sending the email. Check if this is the case by looking at your anti virus logs.

Beyond that, you might want to check if firewall is fine, you can connect to the SMTP server etc.

Comment: Solved the problem, spoke with our network technicians and fromthe regular client network port 25 was blocked. Will have to try and do this with outlook and comobject

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0) 
$Mail.Recipients.Add("XXX@YYY.ZZZ") 
$Mail.Subject = "PS1 Script TestMail" 
$Mail.Body = "Test Mail"
$Mail.Send() 

# you can use this for HTML-Mails 
# $Mail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><HEAD>Text<B>BOLD</B>  <span style='color:#E36C0A'>Color Text</span></HEAD></HTML>" 
# you can use this for attache a file 
# $Mail.Attachments.Add("D:\scripte\ol.txt")
```

For further [reference](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_function_send_email.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Changing port to 25 works, but why ?